# How to make the difference of two subsequent iterations a condition in JAVA

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, difference

I am trying to terminate a loop once the difference of two subsequent iterations is below a certain number.

```
public static double squareRoot(double desiredRoot){
        double answer = 0;
        double estimate = desiredRoot/2;
        double oneCloser;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++){
            oneCloser = (estimate + desiredRoot/estimate)/2;
            estimate = oneCloser;
            if ( Math.abs(oneCloser(i)-oneCloser(i-1))> 0.0001){ // here is my problem
                continue;
            }
            answer = estimate;
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Also, is there a more efficient way for my loop to run than to use i< 10000(big number).

thanks a lot!

erik

Comment: Check out [`while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loops.

Comment: Why reimplement [`Math.sqrt(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt-double-)?

Comment: As keppil says: Java supports more than one type of loop.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Maybe because that is a good assignment to understand what all that programming and math stuff is 'bout?

Comment: @Jägermeister But the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)?

Comment: Thank you keppil and jagermeister. The problem is that even with a while loop, the program wont work because the line if '( Math.abs(oneCloser(i)-oneCloser(i-1))> 0.0001)' gives the error erroneous tree type <any>

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~kjg/cse131/Notes/SquareRoot/sqrt.html),

```
public static double squareRoot(double desiredRoot){
        double answer = 0;
        double estimate = desiredRoot/2;
        double oneCloser;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++){

            double temp = desiredRoot/estimate
            if ( Math.abs(temp-estimate)> 0.0001){ // here is my problem
                break;
            }
            estimate = (estimate + desiredRoot/estimate)/2;
        }
        return estimate;
    }
```

Using a for loop will not guarantee that this will out put the correct answer with respect to the requirement which is `Math.abs(temp-estimate)> 0.0001`. But we know for sure that this code is definitely going to finish.

We can also use a while loop. But there is no time guarantee.

```
 public static double squareRoot(double desiredRoot){

            double answer = 0;
            double estimate = desiredRoot/2;
            double oneCloser;
            boolean correct = false;
            while (correct){

                double temp = desiredRoot/estimate
                if ( Math.abs(temp-estimate)> 0.0001){ // here is my problem
                    correct = true;
                }
                estimate = (estimate + desiredRoot/estimate)/2;
            }
            return estimate;
        }
```

> Warning: Have not tested this code, just wrote on the edit view

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to put your logic in a `do {} while();` loop, this will let your loop run through 1 iteration which will set a previous value and calculate 1 additional iteration.

```
public static double squareRoot(double desiredRoot) {
    double previousEst;
    double currentEst = desiredRoot/2;
    do {
        // store our previous value for reference in the loop condition.
        previousEst = currentEst;
        // calculate the new estimate based on the current value.
        currentEst = (currentEst + desiredRoot/currentEst)/2;
    } while(Math.abs(currentEst - previousEst) > 0.0001); // keep going until we have reached a very small deviation.

    // return our estimate
    return currentEst;
}
```

Comment: Very appreciated, the only problem I see with this is that currentEst = prevEst. As such, the difference is 0 which will always be smaller than 0.0001. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @erikmagiic have you tried to execute this methods? Im not sure I follow the 'issue' you outlined. The statement reads `previousEst = currentEst` not the other way around. The while loops statement is valid as far as I can see. For fun I ran some tests which compared this methods value vs `Math.sqrt(double)`. The results are `Adverage deviation: 3.024E-13` and `Max deviation: 2.44E-9` (number truncated for space).